# Ехидна: змея или австралийское животное?

Tags: значение-слов

Я знаю, что Ехидна — это персонаж древнегреческой мифологии. Но одновременно в Библии это слово употребляется по отношению к змее. Только не пойму: к какому-то конкретному виду или к любой змее? Плюс, с какой-то стати, так же называется яйцекладущее млекопитающее из Австралии.
Так что такое все-таки ехидна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Библии много грецизмов, это грецизм: Ехи́дна, Эхидна (др.-греч. Ἔχιδνα, буквально «гадюка») —   исполинская полуженщина-полузмея .

http://wiki.bks-tv.ru/wiki/%D0%95%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)

В биологии ехидны - представители второго семейства отряда однопроходных  , покрытые иглами, как дикобразы, но по типу питания напоминающие муравьедов.
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_biology/757/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE   Может, потому и назвали так, что похожи на что-то экзотическое,нереальное,мифическое, помесь какая-то, фото посмотрите, я бы тоже за что-то мифическое приняла.